# Program crashes after removing an element from vector

Tags: c++

I have to implement a binary heap represented as a vector in c++ and everything works fine except for my removeMin() method. Job is a class that has 3 data fields and jobs is a vector containing a list of this class. I can call it with no problems until I try to print out the elements or insert a new one, then I got this error:

```
Debug Assertion Failed!
Program: C:\SYSTEM32\MSVCP140D.dll
File: c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\inclue\vector
Line: 1234

Expression: vector subscript out of range

For information on how your program can cause an assertion
failure, see the Visual C++ documentation on asserts.

(Press Retry to debug the application)
```

Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong?

```
 Job Batch::removeMinJob() {
     if (isEmpty()) 
         throw("No jobs are present.");
     
     Job temp = jobs[0];
     jobs.erase(jobs.begin());
     return temp;
}

bool Batch::isEmpty() {
    return jobs.empty();
}

std::vector<Job> jobs;
```

Comment: What does `isEmpty()` look like? Why not simply `jobs.empty()`?

Comment: What does `valgrind` say (ideally on a `-g`-compiled binary)?

Comment: We don't know what `isEmpty()` does (it may have bugs) and we don't know what `job` and what `jobs` are. Please show a [mcve] and tell us the verbatim message the crash prints. Also show that `isEmpty` does.

Comment: From the error message it seems that the `jobs` vector is empty. Run the program with the debugger and look at the stack trace, this will show you what line of your code exactly has triggered the crash. If you don't know how to use the debugger, it's a great opportunity to learn it now, especially as the Visual Studio debugger is very easy to use.

Comment: BTW, *never* throw a string. You may think that will print the error message being thrown, but I've seen it *not* do that. Always throw something derived from `std::exception`.

Comment: Are you trying to implement a multithreaded program? Is Job just an alias for vector? It might be helpful if you could provide these details.